# SQL and Group By query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have table material :

```
 - id: int
 - Product: varchar (100)
 - Content: text 
 - price: double
```

I would like to display list of materials with a  group by product with the last price 
I tried with:

```
 SELECT  * FROM materiel GROUP BY produit ORDER BY id
```

But it appears to me a group by product with the first prize

```
13, product1, dell, 25
14, product2, hp, 4 
17, product3, acer, 15
```

the query without using group by

```
13, product1, dell, 25
14, product2, hp, 4 
16, product1, acer, 35
17, product3, acer, 15
```

I would like this show

```
14, product2, hp, 4
16, product1, acer, 35 
17, product3, acer, 15
```

Comment: Show us the plain table data.

Comment: MySQL or MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved...

Comment: `ORDER BY` gets executed after `GROUP BY`. Here is what happens: You group by produit, so you get one row per produit. One is the produit; one is one of its contents (you don't say which one, such as `max(content)`), one is one of its prices, again arbitrarily chosen, and one is one of its IDs. Then you sort all products by their picked IDs. Which makes no sense, as you can see. Always use aggregate functions on the columns that are not in the `GROUP BY` clause - unless you are absolutely sure what you are doing. It may help you to set ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY mode as long as you are learning this.

Comment: _But it appears to me a group by product with the first prize_ - This is not defined as the case, although often true, MySQL can use the first row the last row or any intermediate row for non GROUP BY / aggregate values. No defined reason why it couldn't use different columns values from different rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `IN()` statement :

```
SELECT * FROM product p
WHERE p.product,p.id IN(SELECT p1.product,max(p1.id)
                        FROM product p1
                        GROUP BY p1.product)
```

Or a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT p.* FROM product p
INNER JOIN (SELECT p1.product,max(p1.id) as max_id
            FROM product p1
            GROUP BY p1.product) p1
 ON(p.id = p1.max_id and p.product = p1.product)
```

Answer (score 1):

One method uses a correlated subquery:

```
select m.*
from material m
where m.id = (select max(m2.id) from material m2 where m2.product = m.product);
```

I prefer this method because the subquery can take advantage of an index on `material(product, id)`, so it can be faster than an aggregation approach.  Also, if you have additional conditions (say `price > 100`), then this should be faster.

Or, in SQL Server, the typical way uses `row_number()`:

```
select m.*
from (select m.*,
             row_number() over (partition by product order by id desc) as seqnum
      from material m
     ) m
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  m.* 
FROM materiel m
LEFT JOIN materiel m1
ON m.produit  = m1.produit 
  AND m.id<m1.id
WHERE m1.id IS NULL
```